# App Link Facebook for unity

Tags: android, unity3d, facebook

Куда страница пропала? из видео https://youtu.be/28ANaG8syFc?t=343 на 5:43 
ссылка на создания app link https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/414551098959938/?platform=app-links-host

она не работает, кто знает по каким причинам и где взять этот Applink для метода FB.Mobile.AppInvite (?) в настоящее время?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, они убрали, так как:

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Links Hosting
>   is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.

Старые будут работать до 5 Февраля, новые не создать. Вообще, читайте [официальный блог](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/):

> App Links Host: Starting today, we will be sunsetting App Links Host.
>   For the next 90 days, GET operations will still work, but POST will no
>   longer be supported. On 2/6, all calls to the endpoint will fail with
>   error.